# Multiply two matrix in cuda c

Tags: cuda

I have to matrices A(32*32) and B(32*n), in which 'n' is coming from inputs and is between 2000 to 2000000.

I have two kind of inputs one is integers between 0 to 255 and the other one is 0,1. this multiplication is in a loop that iterates 3000 times. B(32*n) comes form input and is constant in all of the iterations but A(32*32) can change in each iteration.

```
//read B from file
//read A from file
double D[3000];
for(int i = 0; i < 3000; i++)
{
    C = multiply(A, B);
    // D[i] = mean of all elements in C
    // build A from B using D[i] (this part is really complicated sequential process that contains lots of if and switches)
}
```

What is the fastest way to do this?
thank you.

Comment: did you try anything? how about ready made solution such as [cuBLAS](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuBLAS)?

Comment: Actually i'm good at c++ but I'm a beginner in cuda. I need to optimize a code and this part of code takes most of time. I didn't try any thing yet and i hope you guys can help me.

Comment: You haven't said anything about the types. Single, double, integer? (that makes a huge difference in performance, depending on which GPU you are planning on using). Also, If this is the only part of the code you are planning on moving to the GPU, prepare to be disappointed. There isn't a lot of FLOPs when in inner product is only 32 x 32.

Comment: I have to kind of input one is integers between 0 to 255 and the other one is 0,1.
this multiplication is in a loop that iterates 3000 times. B(32*n)  comes form input and is constant in all of the iterations but A(32*32) can change in each iteration.

Comment: Those are all incredibly important details to your question which will likely change the answer. Please edit your question to *precisely* describe your problem and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: In fact, what you are really doing is computing 32xn independent integer sums of the rows of 32x32 matrix, where each sum has a variable number of elements (between 0 and 32). That is a very different problem from the way you have decribed it

Comment: the multiplication and mean after it takes more than 95% of time, i hope you can help me do it in cuda.

Comment: You should make an attempt yourself.  Questions asking others to translate code for you are frowned on.  Furthermore, if you have no understanding of CUDA, it does you little good to drop a piece of CUDA code in your lap.

Answer (score 2):

Nobody here is going to write code for you, that is not what Stack Overflow is intended for. However, it would appear to be that there are a number of characteristics of the problem which you should be looking to exploit to improve the performance of your code:

1. Recognise that because one of the matrices only contains 0 or 1 and you are performing this in integer, what you are describing as matrix multiplication is really a large number of independent sparse sums
2. Recognise that because the next operation is to compute an average, you don't actually have to store the intermediate dot products and could directly perform a reduction on partial results of the matrix row summation

There are probably parallel primitives in the thrust library which you could use for prototyping, and an optimal hand written kernel would be aiming to fuse both the first and most of the second part of the operation into a single kernel.

Comment: thank you. but I think you got me wrong. I dont want any body write my hole code for me. thats why i asked just the matrix multiplication part first. I want to know how to deal with threads in case that they are to many and we dont know how many at the beginning.

Comment: even if you can send me a sample code that deals with the same problem can be helpful. you asked me what the hole problem is and i told you.

Comment: Sorry, but I am not going to send you anything. I have provided some suggestions for how to implement the operation in a way that should be fast for the GPU. Now it is your job to write it. If you have a problem with your implementation, thenby all means come back and ask a new question about that problem.